# proof for the alternate version of strong induction

Tags: induction

> Prove:
>
> Let $t$ be a ﬁxed integer and $j$ a ﬁxed positive integer.
>
> Show that if $P(t), P(t+1),\dotsc,P(t+j)$ are true
> and $[P(t)\land P(t+ 1) \land \dotsb \land P(k)]\implies P(k+1)$ is true
> for every integer $k \ge t$, then $P(n)$ is true for all
> integers $n$ with $n \ge t$.

I'm pretty lost on this.  I suspected that contrapositive might be the easiest way to show this but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the statement is false, and let $n_0 \ge t$ be least such that $P(n_0)$ fails. (We must have $n_0 > t+j$, but this is kind of irrelevant.)

You know that $P(t) \wedge P(t+1) \wedge \cdots \wedge P(n_0-1)$ holds by minimality of $n_0$, and hence $P(n_0)$ holds by the given condition, contradicting your assumption that $P(n_0)$ fails.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helps. Out of curiosity, how would you prove it by strong induction directly?  I think that's the direction we were intended supposed to go in.

Comment: induction, well-ordering, these are axioms. They are logically equivalent. We must start somewhere.

Comment: @kowitzha: What I did was prove your statement from the well-ordering principle. You can prove strong induction in exactly the same way -- this is why I said the $j$ is irrelevant: omitting all that stuff and just requiring that $P(t)$ holds (i.e. for $j=0$) is *exactly* the statement of strong induction.

Comment: But doesn't the formal statement of strong induction say that it has to start at 1 rather than at some t?  What would the actual direct proof using strong induction with a base case and inductive step actually look like?  It looks pretty much trivial to me, like there is really nothing to show.

Comment: @kowitzha: If your strong induction principle starts at $1$ then just replace $t$ by $1$ in the proof.

Comment: How can we rigorously justify doing that?

Comment: By writing the proof out.